# Mysql to postgres function

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I currently self-studying `postgresql`. I used to study `mysql`. How to convert my code in postgresql?

```
function user_exists($username){

     $username= sanitize($username);

     $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM user WHERE `username` = '$username'");

     return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;

}
```

Comment: Step 1: Learn PDO. Step 2: Use **placeholder values** in prepared statements like your life depends on it, because it basically does.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like SHA1 or MD5.